# Как настроить position в анимации

Tags: unity3d

Я делаю 2д игру на Unity и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть анимированный бегущий спрайт. Я хочу добавить к спрайту игрока объект палки и анимировать его так, чтобы в каждом кадре она меняла свое положение в зависимости от кадра спрайта (нес ее в руке). Но когда я настраиваю параметр position палки, она плавно меняет свое положение между фреймами. Как мне сделать так чтобы она "*телепортировалась*" от одного положения к другому.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Как убрать плавное изменение положения палки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В окне Animation снизу переключи с Dopesheet на Curves, ты увидишь кривые разноцветные линии это твоя анимация каждая точка на линии это позиции которую палка принимает,  между точками переходы плавные, что бы это убрать как ты и хочешь - нажми на каждую точку и поверни появившуюся серую линию так чтобы переходы стали ступенчатыми (как на картинке у меня).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]